# Hibernate Junit H2 In memory database test case changing fields in the development db

Tags: java, hibernate, junit

I have developed a project using Hibernate. I am trying to test it using Junit with H2 in memory db but the test case is creating fields in the db that I am using it for development. 
Here is my code :

***UserDAO.java***

```
public interface UserDAO {

    public void addUser(String username, String password);
    public List<String> getUsers();
}
```

***UserDAOImpl.java***

```
public class UserDAOImpl implements UserDAO {
    public static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserDAOImpl.class);
    private static Session session;

    private static void beginSession() {
        session = DbUtils.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
    }

    @Override
    public void addUser(String username, String password) {
        String encryptedPassword = Utils.encrypt(password);
        User user = new User(username, encryptedPassword);
        beginSession();
        try {
            session.save(user);
            System.out.println(user.getPassword());
            session.getTransaction().commit();
        } catch (SQLGrammarException e) {
            session.getTransaction().rollback();
            LOG.error("Cannot save user", e);
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public List<String> getUsers() {
        beginSession();
        List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
        String hql = "select username from User";
        Query query = null;
        try {
            query = session.createQuery(hql);
            results = query.list();
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            LOG.error("Cannot execute query", e);
        } 
        return results;
    }
}
```

Files for test cases
***SessionFactoryRule.java***

```
 public class SessionFactoryRule implements MethodRule {
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    private Transaction transaction;
    private Session session;
@Override
public Statement apply(final Statement statement, FrameworkMethod method, Object test) {
    return new Statement() {
        @Override
        public void evaluate() throws Throwable {
            sessionFactory = createSessionFactory();
            createSession();
            beginTransaction();
            try {
                statement.evaluate();
            } finally {
                shutdown();
            }
        }
    };
}
private void shutdown() {
    try {
        try {
            try {
                transaction.rollback();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            session.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        sessionFactory.close();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private SessionFactory createSessionFactory() {
    Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
    configuration.addAnnotatedClass(User.class)
    .addAnnotatedClass(Message.class);
    configuration.setProperty("hibernate.dialect",
            "org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect");
    configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.driver_class",
            "org.h2.Driver");
    configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", "jdbc:h2:./data/db");
    configuration.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create");
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory();
    return sessionFactory;
}

public Session createSession() {
    session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    return session;
}

public void commit() {
    transaction.commit();
}

public void beginTransaction() {
    transaction = session.beginTransaction();
}

public Session getSession() {
    return session;
}`
```

Here is my test case

***UserDAOTest.java***

```
public class UserDAOTest {

    @Rule
    public final SessionFactoryRule sf = new SessionFactoryRule();


    @Test
    public void testAddUser() {
    Session session = sf.getSession();
    UserDAOImpl userDAOImpl = new UserDAOImpl();
    String username = "stackoverflow";
    String password = "testing";
    userDAOImpl.addUser(username, password);

    }
}
```

This test case is updating the fields `username` and `password` in the db that I am using while development. How can I stop it and use h2 in-memory db for testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `session = DbUtils.getSessionFactory().openSession()` in the `UserDAOImpl`. This is the reason of using a development database. Your `SessionFactoryRule` is not used at all.

So what you can to do.
The best choice is use to Spring for Hibernate configuration and unit testing.

Other option is to set `sessionFactory` to the `UserDAOImpl` using constructor.

Also, using `static` here is a really very very bad idea

`private static Session session;`